# Enterprise search for e-commerce catalog/site

Tags: open-source, search-engine, sap-netweaver

I am looking for an open-source search engine for e-commerce site. The primary purpose would be to search our product catalog (current master catalog is SAP) but would also like to enable document search at a later point for PDFs. The overall goal is to provide a modern search experience for our customer base.

Required features for the system (from end user perspective):

- The search engine must be compatible with SAP NetWeaver
- Predictive/type ahead search
- Search by synonyms (*car* would show anything taged as *automobile* as well) and phrases (car search for 'Make Modle' or vice versa)
- Faceted

So far I have narrowed the options to Solr, Elasticsearch, and Sphinx (**I am open to additional suggestions, my current research has pointed me in the direction of these three**). All three seem to cover the needs from a front end perspective. I am having trouble understanding the differences from the back end (I have seen this http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com/ & https://sematext.com/blog/2012/08/23/solr-vs-elasticsearch-part-1-overview/ & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284083/choosing-a-stand-alone-full-text-search-server-sphinx-or-solr as well as many other comparisons between these options).

What major difference between these would determine which is best for my use case? Is there a clear winner between these for B2B - ECommerce type websites?

Comment: Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So I hope you're open to other products matching your requirements?

Comment: 100% open to other products being a better fit. I was just stating what my current research had turned up. What I am really after is what I should be looking at as a better deciding factor. Should is there some technical requirement that my team has not discovered that is going to make an option completely unviable or a bad fit.